# What is the difference between a85encode and b85encode?

Tags: python, python-3.4, base85

Python 3.4 added the [**`a85encode`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.a85encode) and [**`b85encode`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b85encode) functions (and their corresponding decoding functions).

What is the difference between the two? The documentation mentions *"They differ by details such as the character map used for encoding."*, but this seems unnecessarily vague.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`a85encode` uses the character mapping:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`
abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
```

with `z` used as a special case to represent four zero bytes (instead of `!!!!!`).

`b85encode` uses the character mapping:

```
0123456789
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
!#$%&()*+-;<=>?@^_`{|}~
```

with no special abbreviations.

---

If you have a choice, I'd recommend you use `a85encode`. It's a bit easier (and more efficient) to implement in `C`, as its character mapping uses all characters in ASCII order, and it's slightly more efficient at storing data containing lots of zeroes, which isn't uncommon for uncompressed binary data.

Comment: How is Ascii85 more efficient than Base85 for storing zeros exactly?

Comment: `a85encode(b'\0\0\0\0')` is `b'z'`. `b85encode(b'\0\0\0\0')` is `b'00000'`.

Comment: That's nice for zeros! but what if you need to encode `z`? I would imagine with Ascii85 you'd be doing `\x7A` quite a bit. I was under the impression the two encodings had the same efficiency overall (4/5).

Comment: @l'L'l I think you're confused. Ascii85 doesn't pass characters through unchanged; `z` isn't used in the character mapping. (It ends at `u`; see above.) So there's no escaping.

Comment: @l'L'l You've totally misconstrued the way the mapping works. All bytes, including 0x7a, can be encoded by Ascii85 and Base85. Each one uses a set of 85 *output* characters to encode those bytes in an expanded form.

Answer (score 9):

**Ascii85** is the predecessor of **Base85**; the primary difference between the two is in-fact the character sets that are used.

[**`Ascii85`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85) uses the character set:

```
ASCII 33 ("!") to ASCII 117 ("u")
```

[**`Base85`**](https://github.com/woolstar/test/tree/master/encode) uses the character set:

```
0–9, A–Z, a–z, !#$%&()*+-;<=>?@^_`{|}~
```

<sub>***These characters are specifically not included in Base85***:</sub>

```
"',./:[]\\
```

**a85encode** and **b85encode** encode/decode **Ascii85** and **Base85** respectively.

Comment: I know this is a late response, but this explanation is seriously confused. Ascii85 encoding was introduced in RFC1924 as an encoding for IPv6 addresses -- however, **this was an April Fool's joke**. It was never intended to be implemented, and has no practical benefits.

Comment: Base85 encoding, on the other hand, was first implemented as part of the `btoa` command-line utility, which was published on USENET sometime before 1990. It clearly cannot have been influenced by RFC1924 (which wasn't published until 1996), nor by 21st-century creations like JSON or git.

Comment: @duskwuff: There is no confusion; I had mentioned last time the misinformation out there, and since it was promptly disregarded I included some it in my answer to make a point. Despite RFC 1924 being a joke, the premise of the encoding isn't entirely impractical in the least — Base85 uses the same character set! Interestingly there some examples which have shown [it can work](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70277/implement-an-encoder-for-rfc-1924-ipv6-addresses).